# The image of a homomorphism is a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have this written down in my notes, but cannot seem to find verification of it. How can I see this fact?

I believe there is a theorem, something along the lines of if a group G is isomorphic to H then, H is a group. Can anybody verify this or point me to the direction I am looking for? Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to write "the image of a subgroup under a homomorphism is a group"?

Comment: No, I have written "the image of the homomorphism is a group" as part of the proof about quotient groups. But what you said makes more sense because I know that if $f$ is a homomorphism, from $G$ to $H$ then $ker(f)$ and $im(f)$ are subgroups of $G$ and $H$ respectively.

Comment: Yes. Subgroups are groups by definition.

Comment: I am confused about what your question really is.

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification!

Comment: I was asking if it is true that the image of a homomorphism is a group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$. Without assuming that $\phi(G)=H$, we claim that $\phi(G)$ has a group structure.

1) identity: clearly $\phi(e)=e$ so this is trivial.

2) associativity: let $g_1,g_2,g_3$ be in $G$. Then $(\phi(g_1)\phi(g_2))\phi(g_2)=\phi(g_1g_2)\phi(g_3)=\phi(g_1g_2g_3)$. From here you can probably see that associativity is basically inherited from the associativity of $G$.

3) closure: we need to show that $\phi(g_1)\phi(g_2)$ is in $H$. Since $\phi(g_1)\phi(g_2)=\phi(g_1g_2)$, this is in $H$.

Basically, each property follows from the group structure of $G$. Of course, this proof is redundant if you have the property you mentioned in the comments. Since $G$ is a subgroup of itself, $\phi(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Is this homomorphic image always a normal subgroup of the codomain?

Comment: @SamuelDíaz consider $G$ a group and $H$ a non-normal subgroup. Then the inclusion mapping $\iota\colon H \hookrightarrow G$ given by $\iota(h) = h$ has image $H$... so no, the image needs not to be a normal subgroup.